# Netbeans / persistence API error

Tags: java, netbeans, persistence

I am following this tutorial, I'm using netbeans 6.5.1  http://www.netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-db-custom.html

When I get to the part where I create the "new entity class from database", which is in the "Customizing the Master/Detail View" section of the tutoiral. I can't ever compile because I get this error in the task list (and I get a runtime error when I run)... Atleast I think these two are related.

```
Error   Named queries can be defined only on an Entity or MappedSuperclass class.   Countries.java  27  C:/Users/Danny/dev/NetBeansProjects/Test/src/test

Error   Named queries can be defined only on an Entity or MappedSuperclass class.   Products.java   28  C:/Users/Danny/dev/NetBeansProjects/Test/src/test
```

note that all I do is do new>entity classes from database, and do exactly as the tutorial says. I stopped on the tutoral at the "Adding Dialog Boxes" heading, because the tutorial writer says the application should be "partially functional" which makes me think it should atleast RUN. I haven't edited the generated code outside of what I've been instructed to do.

This is the output produced by the netbeans output console:

```
run:
Jun 23, 2009 3:03:23 PM org.jdesktop.application.Application$1 run
SEVERE: Application class test.TestApp failed to launch
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named MyBusinessRecordsPU: Provider named oracle.toplink.essentials.PersistenceProvider threw unexpected exception at create EntityManagerFactory: 
oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException
Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [TOPLINK-30005] (Oracle TopLink Essentials - 2.0.1 (Build b09d-fcs (12/06/2007))): oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException
Exception Description: An exception was thrown while searching for persistence archives with ClassLoader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@11b86e7
Internal Exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [TOPLINK-28018] (Oracle TopLink Essentials - 2.0.1 (Build b09d-fcs (12/06/2007))): oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: predeploy for PersistenceUnit [MyBusinessRecordsPU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [TOPLINK-7244] (Oracle TopLink Essentials - 2.0.1 (Build b09d-fcs (12/06/2007))): oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: An incompatible mapping has been encountered between [class test.Products] and [class test.Orders]. This usually occurs when the cardinality of a mapping does not correspond with the cardinality of its backpointer.
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException.exceptionSearchingForPersistenceResources(PersistenceUnitLoadingException.java:143)
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.ejb.cmp3.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:169)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:110)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:83)
        at test.TestView.initComponents(TestView.java:337)
        at test.TestView.(TestView.java:39)
        at test.TestApp.startup(TestApp.java:19)
        at org.jdesktop.application.Application$1.run(Application.java:171)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:597)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [TOPLINK-28018] (Oracle TopLink Essentials - 2.0.1 (Build b09d-fcs (12/06/2007))): oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: predeploy for PersistenceUnit [MyBusinessRecordsPU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [TOPLINK-7244] (Oracle TopLink Essentials - 2.0.1 (Build b09d-fcs (12/06/2007))): oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: An incompatible mapping has been encountered between [class test.Products] and [class test.Orders]. This usually occurs when the cardinality of a mapping does not correspond with the cardinality of its backpointer.
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:643)
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.JavaSECMPInitializer.callPredeploy(JavaSECMPInitializer.java:171)
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.JavaSECMPInitializer.initPersistenceUnits(JavaSECMPInitializer.java:239)
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.JavaSECMPInitializer.initialize(JavaSECMPInitializer.java:255)
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.ejb.cmp3.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:155)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: Exception [TOPLINK-28018] (Oracle TopLink Essentials - 2.0.1 (Build b09d-fcs (12/06/2007))): oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: predeploy for PersistenceUnit [MyBusinessRecordsPU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [TOPLINK-7244] (Oracle TopLink Essentials - 2.0.1 (Build b09d-fcs (12/06/2007))): oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: An incompatible mapping has been encountered between [class test.Products] and [class test.Orders]. This usually occurs when the cardinality of a mapping does not correspond with the cardinality of its backpointer.
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.predeployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:228)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: Exception [TOPLINK-7244] (Oracle TopLink Essentials - 2.0.1 (Build b09d-fcs (12/06/2007))): oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: An incompatible mapping has been encountered between [class test.Products] and [class test.Orders]. This usually occurs when the cardinality of a mapping does not correspond with the cardinality of its backpointer.
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.ValidationException.invalidMapping(ValidationException.java:1069)
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.metadata.MetadataValidator.throwInvalidMappingEncountered(MetadataValidator.java:275)
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.metadata.accessors.OneToManyAccessor.process(OneToManyAccessor.java:161)
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.metadata.accessors.RelationshipAccessor.processRelationship(RelationshipAccessor.java:290)
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.metadata.MetadataProject.processRelationshipDescriptors(MetadataProject.java:579)
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.metadata.MetadataProject.process(MetadataProject.java:512)
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.metadata.MetadataProcessor.processAnnotations(MetadataProcessor.java:246)
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.ejb.cmp3.persistence.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processORMetadata(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:370)
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:607)
        ... 18 more


 The following providers:
oracle.toplink.essentials.ejb.cmp3.EntityManagerFactoryProvider
Returned null to createEntityManagerFactory.

        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:154)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:83)
        at test.TestView.initComponents(TestView.java:337)
        at test.TestView.(TestView.java:39)
        at test.TestApp.startup(TestApp.java:19)
        at org.jdesktop.application.Application$1.run(Application.java:171)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:597)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Application class test.TestApp failed to launch
        at org.jdesktop.application.Application$1.run(Application.java:177)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:597)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named MyBusinessRecordsPU: Provider named oracle.toplink.essentials.PersistenceProvider threw unexpected exception at create EntityManagerFactory: 
oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException
Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [TOPLINK-30005] (Oracle TopLink Essentials - 2.0.1 (Build b09d-fcs (12/06/2007))): oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException
Exception Description: An exception was thrown while searching for persistence archives with ClassLoader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@11b86e7
Internal Exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [TOPLINK-28018] (Oracle TopLink Essentials - 2.0.1 (Build b09d-fcs (12/06/2007))): oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: predeploy for PersistenceUnit [MyBusinessRecordsPU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [TOPLINK-7244] (Oracle TopLink Essentials - 2.0.1 (Build b09d-fcs (12/06/2007))): oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: An incompatible mapping has been encountered between [class test.Products] and [class test.Orders]. This usually occurs when the cardinality of a mapping does not correspond with the cardinality of its backpointer.
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException.exceptionSearchingForPersistenceResources(PersistenceUnitLoadingException.java:143)
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.ejb.cmp3.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:169)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:110)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:83)
        at test.TestView.initComponents(TestView.java:337)
        at test.TestView.(TestView.java:39)
        at test.TestApp.startup(TestApp.java:19)
        at org.jdesktop.application.Application$1.run(Application.java:171)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:597)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [TOPLINK-28018] (Oracle TopLink Essentials - 2.0.1 (Build b09d-fcs (12/06/2007))): oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: predeploy for PersistenceUnit [MyBusinessRecordsPU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [TOPLINK-7244] (Oracle TopLink Essentials - 2.0.1 (Build b09d-fcs (12/06/2007))): oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: An incompatible mapping has been encountered between [class test.Products] and [class test.Orders]. This usually occurs when the cardinality of a mapping does not correspond with the cardinality of its backpointer.
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:643)
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.JavaSECMPInitializer.callPredeploy(JavaSECMPInitializer.java:171)
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.JavaSECMPInitializer.initPersistenceUnits(JavaSECMPInitializer.java:239)
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.JavaSECMPInitializer.initialize(JavaSECMPInitializer.java:255)
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.ejb.cmp3.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:155)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: Exception [TOPLINK-28018] (Oracle TopLink Essentials - 2.0.1 (Build b09d-fcs (12/06/2007))): oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: predeploy for PersistenceUnit [MyBusinessRecordsPU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [TOPLINK-7244] (Oracle TopLink Essentials - 2.0.1 (Build b09d-fcs (12/06/2007))): oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: An incompatible mapping has been encountered between [class test.Products] and [class test.Orders]. This usually occurs when the cardinality of a mapping does not correspond with the cardinality of its backpointer.
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.predeployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:228)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: Exception [TOPLINK-7244] (Oracle TopLink Essentials - 2.0.1 (Build b09d-fcs (12/06/2007))): oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: An incompatible mapping has been encountered between [class test.Products] and [class test.Orders]. This usually occurs when the cardinality of a mapping does not correspond with the cardinality of its backpointer.
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.ValidationException.invalidMapping(ValidationException.java:1069)
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.metadata.MetadataValidator.throwInvalidMappingEncountered(MetadataValidator.java:275)
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.metadata.accessors.OneToManyAccessor.process(OneToManyAccessor.java:161)
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.metadata.accessors.RelationshipAccessor.processRelationship(RelationshipAccessor.java:290)
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.metadata.MetadataProject.processRelationshipDescriptors(MetadataProject.java:579)
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.metadata.MetadataProject.process(MetadataProject.java:512)
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.metadata.MetadataProcessor.processAnnotations(MetadataProcessor.java:246)
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.ejb.cmp3.persistence.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processORMetadata(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:370)
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:607)
        ... 18 more


 The following providers:
oracle.toplink.essentials.ejb.cmp3.EntityManagerFactoryProvider
Returned null to createEntityManagerFactory.

        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:154)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:83)
        at test.TestView.initComponents(TestView.java:337)
        at test.TestView.(TestView.java:39)
        at test.TestApp.startup(TestApp.java:19)
        at org.jdesktop.application.Application$1.run(Application.java:171)
        ... 8 more
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

I'm thinking my netbeans application must be misconfigured or something, I can't seem to find anyone with the same problem as myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to have been a bug in netbeans, I did a fresh install and it seems to work now.

Comment: I got the same error in NetBeans 6.8. Was the bug re-introduced somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Reinstalled - same problem.
Ran Revo uninstaller on default settings.
Reinstalled.
This time I created entities for the Countries & Products tables as soon as I could in the process - immediately after the New Project wizard.
I'm not sure if that made the difference, but this time all was well

Answer (score 0):

Updating the Netbeans IDE worked for me. I didn't need a fresh install.

Answer (score 0):

Update: This error still exists in Netbeans 7.4. 
 Annotated Entities within the -war (Web - ) Module of an Enterprise Application still cause the "NamedQueries can be defined only..." error,
 the same classes in the ejb - Module won't. 
 Obviously that's where Entity - Classes should reside anyway,
  I'v been moving them to the Web- Module for generating the JSF - Pages, but as this was not working properly due to the mentioned issue 
 after restarting the ide the pages could be generated from the EJB - Module too.